# OSX/Linux, slow down the output from terminal

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I'm printing to screen a long text file that scrolls very very quickly on my screen, is there a way to slow down the scrolling? In other words is there a system setting that controls the speed at which output is displayed to screen (OSX/Linux).

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: No.

Extended version: There are other solutions. You could pick from one of the following:

- Use pipes. Using pipes allows you to redirect terminal output and to review it in your own speed. The appropiate symbol is `|`. Redirect the output to programs like `less` ore `more`. Both allow you to scroll through the output via pressing return, you can exit any time by pressing `q`. For instance, for handling a long directory listing, you could use

  ```
  ls | more
  ```
- Redirect your output into a file. If your output is cached in a file, it's persistent and allows you to open it with an editor of your choice to view (and edit) it. The symbol is `>`.

  ```
  touch log.txt # create the file
  ls > log.txt
  nano log.txt # use nano text editor to view
  ```
- `script` allows you to record entire terminal sessoins. This might be an overkill for your use-case, but is really useful. From the man page:

  > script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is
  >        useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive session
  >        as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out
  >        later with lpr(1).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`less`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_less.htm) to page through files; you can page back and forth, search, etc.

`xterm` has limited control over scrolling speed; most other terminal emulators have none, because that's the wrong way to step through a file when you can use a program like `less` to filter the output.