# How to slow down tail'ing logs

Tags: shell

I am using `tail -f /var/app/support/logs/access.log` to look for some abnormal traffic in my logs.

My problem is that I have hundreds of lines coming in at the same time making it impossible to read.

Is there a way to still tail logs but just slow down the output?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but no.

Tail isn't very useful here, you are probably better off using `less +F` or piping it into a file.

[This should explain it well enough](https://www.brianstorti.com/stop-using-tail/)

Answer (score 0):

We can try below option :

```
 tail -f /var/app/support/logs/access.log & sleep 10 ;kill -9 $!
 or
 tail -f /var/app/support/logs/access.log > /tmp/output
 Ctrl Z   (On keyboard)
 Post this read /tmp/output for analysis.
```

[OSX/Linux, slow down the output from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573906/osx-linux-slow-down-the-output-from-terminal)